# Android multiscreen different layoutfiles for tablets

Tags: android, layout, directory, screen-size, multiscreen

I have to make an app which runs on 7" tablets with a resolution of 800x480 and also 1024x600.
The most importan tablet of both is the one with 1024x600 so I placed my layout files in a layoutfolder with the name "layout-sw600dp" and it looks good.

The problem now, is that the tablet with 800x480 resolution is also taking the "layout-sw600dp" folder and my layout isn't looking good. So I have to make some changes, but without destroying the layout for the bigger tablet.

Any idea what I can do?

thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: Do you have a res/layout/ folder for the 800x480 to pull the layout from?

Comment: i tried diffent layout folders for 800x480, but it get's always the layout from the sw600dp folder. I tried "res/layout/large" and also "sw480dp" etc.

Comment: I tried to many layout folder combinations, but everytime it chooses the same for both resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok found a solution. The problem is, that both tablets are in the same android layout group. So I had to modify my layout in this way to fit for both. I had to use more dp settings and scaletype="fitxy" for images, instead of using "wrap_content".